# How do I explain a 2 week job overlap?

Tags: job-change, india, background-check

I was working in this Organization X when I got an offer from other Organization Y. The joining for Organization Y was in 45 days but the notice period for Organization X was 2 months. Here is where things get complex.

I put my papers and asked my manager (X Firm) to release me early, to which he agreed initially; as a result I completed formalities for Y firm.

After a month, the Manager denied to release me and asked to serve full notice period, which I couldn't as I had to join Y in 15 days.

I anyhow worked for the extra 15 days after which I left X and joined Y, post which I had a word with HR of X and got my experience letter.

The issue is that in my offer letter from Y, joining date in 15th of May, however in my experience letter, my Last Working Day is reflected as 31st May (2 months of notice period).

I am concerned about how should I explain this to any future organizations. Will they listen to me? Will this pose a problem in Background Verification?

Comment: Are you required to show future employers your offer letters from previous jobs? Or are you assuming this information would also be incorrect elsewhere?

Comment: I doubted if my company X will respond in a different way to these checks.

Comment: If this explanation seems worthy enough, that's what I'll do Joe!

Comment: I am going thru a similar situation right now Please tell me if it in any way affected your future employments?

Answer (score 14):

If this comes up in interviews or pre-screening calls, I would simply explain it to them much as you explained it here. This seems like an easily understandable predicament a person would find themselves in.

Comment: Thank you Jesse! I had been losing sleep thinking about this. You resolved it in 2 sentences.

Comment: My pleasure.  Best of luck to you!

Answer (score 9):

In my experience, nobody is going to ask about the concrete day - usually, you express work period in months.

> Company X - July 2017 - May 2018
>
> Company Y - May 2018 - Present.

Why would someone be interested in the exact day?

Comment: I always discount people who start on odd numbered days - clear sign of unreliability (!) :P

Comment: Does the actual date matter for any rational reason? Of course not, but some countries have persnickety bureaucracy when it comes to employment verification. In India, "release letters" are required and these have dates. The fussy paperwork is just a burden that job candidates have to manage. The US has it's own paperwork burdens (in other areas) which are just as insane.

Comment: @Leo, why would you do that? That looks absolutely bizarre to me.

Comment: @gnasher729 The ":P" in Leo's comment was a smiley.

Answer (score 6):

Read it straight: There is **no overlap** in practice. That is just a mismatched documentation which needs to be corrected.

You can leave out the exact dates if you'd want, while mentioning about experiences in future interviews, however if you *have to* explain, explain the same way you did here.

Also, your experience letter from Y will contain the *actual* date of joining, so there would be no overlapping, when you'll go for another company in future.

Comment: Thank you Sourav. So, ideally I should ask the X firm to get this corrected, right?

Comment: @TanmaySharma No, you should ask Y to put the exact date of joining in their experience / releasing letter.